# How to create schemas for Web service/wcf service

Tags: web-services, wcf

I am new to BizTalk, I wanted to create schemas for Web service/WCF service.
please let me know, what I need to create. I have installed the WCF service in VS 2019.
please share the Microsoft docs link here. so that I can follow

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hope these docs can help you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/publish-schemas-as-wcf-services--use-the-biztalk-wcf-service-publishing-wizard

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/wcf-adapters-property-schema-and-properties

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/using-wcf-services